# Fragment is overlapping

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have created an app when i'm testing my app or i clicked on back button my fragment is overlapping other fragment. I don't know why it's happening. Please help me i need help..
My codes

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SharedPreferences pref;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        pref = getPreferences(0);
        initFragment();
    }

    private void initFragment(){
        Fragment fragment;
        if(pref.getBoolean(Constants.IS_LOGGED_IN,false)){
            fragment = new ProfileFragment();
        }else {
            fragment = new LoginFragment();
        }
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_frame,fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="#ff51b46d"
    tools:context="com.example.hldev.docup.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.hldev.docup.MainActivity">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Uploads.java

```
     public class Uploads extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

            @Nullable
            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_uploads, container, false);
                ivAttachment = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.ivAttachment);

                tv_name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
                tv_email = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_email);
                bUpload = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.b_upload);
                tvFileName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_file_name);
                ivAttachment.setOnClickListener(this);
                bUpload.setOnClickListener(this);
                return  view;
            }


 private void goToProfile(){

        Fragment profile = new ProfileFragment();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_frame,profile);
        ft.commit();
    }
    }
```

Comment: instead of replacing trying adding.

Comment: I have created 3 fragments all fragment is overlapping, i call fragment by it's function  private void goToProfile(){

        Fragment profile = new ProfileFragment();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_frame,profile);
        ft.commit();
    } but fragment is overlapping

Comment: Do one thing, give the background as white of every fragment layout, then try.

Comment: means i have to add color in R.layout.activity_uploads (fragment layout) or  main_activity.layout..

Comment: Make your all layout with background White.

Answer (score 1):

Just set a background color to your new `<fragment />` in XML file or else it will be transparent and show a replaced fragment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; 
    xmlns:tools="schemas.android.com/tools"; 
    android:id="@+id/frag24" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"> 
  <RelativeLayout 
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="@color/green"> 
      <!-- Your Content -->  
      </RelativeLayout> 
</FrameLayout >
```

Comment: please share an example

Comment: i have added it, but when i rotate the screen and click on back button button fragment is overlapped.

Comment: @sangavi when you put the code, put it in the answer, not on the comment of answer.

Answer (score 0):

set white background color of your parent layout of your `activity_uploads`. also do same with all layout which you use in `Fragment`.

Comment: but if i want to fragment color green?? how can i add it?

Comment: Please share a coding example

Comment: then you have to add android:background="#00FF00" line to your parent layout of your XML.

Comment: like this activity_uploads <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="#00FF00"
    tools:context="com.example.hldev.docup.Uploads">

Answer (score 0):

replace your code with below.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
    tools:context="com.example.hldev.docup.Uploads">
```

Comment: Have you test this?

Comment: i have added android:background="@color/frag" in all fragment layout

Comment: <color name="frag">#ff51b46d</color>

Comment: Then please just click on up arrow for my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much with my Heart :)

Comment: can you please try with my both answer.